# Is it possible to skip a test generated from multiple @pytest.mark.parametrize lines?

Tags: pytest

I have a pytest test function with multiple @pytest.mark.parametrize lines. The values for each parameterised variable can take either 0 or 1. Some of the combination generated cannot happen and should be skipped i.e. in my example when subcontact takes the value 0 and when fast track takes the value 1, it should be skipped. Is it possible to achieve this with the multiple @pytest.mark.parametrize fixture?

I attempted this with the code below but no tests were reported as skipped when I ran the tests.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('prospect', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('client', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('subcontact', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('default', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('primary_contact', [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('fast_track', [0, pytest.param(1, marks=pytest.mark.skipif('subcontact' == 0,
                                                                                    reason='Cannot happen'))])
def test_prospect_registration(prospect, client, subcontact, default,
                               primary_contact,
                               fast_track):
    pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest possibililty is probably to skip the specific test inside the test body:

```py
...
def test_prospect_registration(prospect, client, subcontact, default,
                               primary_contact,
                               fast_track):
    if fast_track == 1 and subcontact == 0:
        pytest.skip('Cannot happen')
    ...
```

You could also do the skipping in a fixture based on th test name (the parameters are listed from the last `mark.parametrize` decorator up):

```py
import re

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_unwanted(request):
    if re.match(r'test_prospect_registration\[1-.*-.*-.0.*-.*\]', item.name)
        pytest.skip('Cannot happen')
```

or you could do the same in `pytest_collection_modifyitems`:

**conftest.py**

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        if re.match(r'test_prospect_registration\[1-.*-.*-.0.*-.*\]', item.name):
            item.add_marker('skip')
```