# How to add parametrized test data marker dependent on fixture parameter

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to `pytest` and have not been able to solve my problem by reading the pytest docs or searching on google.

I have written a custom parametrize fixture, and I have a parametrized test that uses said fixture.  I want to mark some of the data as `XFAIL` if, and only if, the fixture parameter is a certain value.

Here's a sample code

```py
import pytest


class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def foo():
    a = A("-1")
    return a


class TestExample:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=["1", "2"])
    def my_fixture(self, foo, request):
        foo.set(request.param)
        return foo

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        argnames="val",
        argvalues=[
            pytest.param(1,),
            pytest.param(2,),
            pytest.param(3,),
            pytest.param(4,),
        ]
    )
    def test_example(self, my_fixture: A, val: int):
        assert str(my_fixture.value) == str(val)
```

In the sample, the test has 4 data sets, and the `my_fixture` fixture has 2 parameters, causing 8 test cases in total.  Out of these 8 tests, only 2 will pass, while the other 6 will fail. I want to mark the 6 failing tests as `XFAIL`. My preference is to keep the test case independent of test data.  That is, I don't want to put logic that state when a test should fails (as adding parametrized data will likely require updating the test).

Ideally, I would do something similar to

```py
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        argnames="val",
        argvalues=[
            pytest.param(1, marks=pytest.mark.xfail("my_fixture.value != 1", reason="Expecting a failure"),
            pytest.param(2, marks=pytest.mark.xfail("my_fixture.value != 2", reason="Expecting a failure"),
            pytest.param(3, marks=pytest.mark.xfail("my_fixture.value != 3", reason="Expecting a failure"),
            pytest.param(4, marks=pytest.mark.xfail("my_fixture.value != 4", reason="Expecting a failure")),
        ]
    )
    def test_example(self, my_fixture: A, val: int):
        assert str(my_fixture.value) == str(val)
```

Any suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258929/12480730) about skipping some of the parameters - please check if this may work for you (using `pytest.xfail` instead of `pytest.skip`).

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing as a workaround, but the test case has knowledge of the test data.  I would like to avoid that if possible.  Also, using `pytest.xfail` in the test body will not run the test, which defies the purpose if I want to add the `strict=True`.

Comment: I see. The only way I can think of is the third option in that answer (using `pytest_collection_modifyitems`) to set the `xfail` marker in the tests where needed, though you have to check the test id or test name for that.